# WMS layer connected to SQL database

Tags: wms, sql, database, connection, openlayers-2

It is possible to connect a WMS layer to a SQL database or other type of database?

Example: I have created an application with GeoServer and OpenLayers. Now I can see the data from attribute table. But can I make the SHP layer to connect to a SQL database by a custom ID? I want to use this to update some data directly from SQL. After the update was made, I can see in GeoServer the data updated.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to indicate whether you are using OpenLayers 2 or OpenLayers 3, please?

Comment: I am using OpenLayers2

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but GeoServer has a SQL Server Plugin: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlserver.html if that is what you are after. It comes with PostgreSQL database support natively.

Comment: In QGIS, you have a shapefile and you create a ID for each polygon. With that ID you can bring data in attribute table with a CSV file using JOIN. The CSV file must contain that ID from shapefile. In QGIS, I managed to insert a DBF file and make a join with shapefile. Everytime I update the DBF file, the attribute table of the shapefile is updated in real-time. I wondered if it is possible to use same operations or schema in Geoserver and Openlayers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a database through some application, and that database is the source of a WMS provided by GeoServer accessed by OpenLayers, then Yes it is possible, as per the answer provided by @maw269.

If you want users to be able to edit the data in the database through OpenLayers, then that is also possible, but not using WMS, for that you will need a WFS-T service, which can be provided by GeoServer.